# What if Binding object has two paths specified in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

How does this Binding work?

```
{Binding P1, Path=P2}
```

1) Will it Bind to P1?

2) To P2?

3) Will it work as MultiBinding?

4) Will it work as PriorityBinding?

Comment: Should be easy enough to check.

Comment: I checked though. It doesn't even seem to be allowed to compile.
But I've got this question in my test without "will not be compiled" option.

Comment: `It doesn't even seem to be allowed to compile.` If it doesn't compile, I am not sure I understand the question? It sounds like the answer to `How does this Binding work?` is **it doesn't work**.

Comment: While the XAML designer complains about the expression, it does compile. So just try it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Will it Bind to P1?

No.

> 2) To P2?

Yes.

> 3) Will it work as MultiBinding?

No.

> 4) Will it work as PriorityBinding?

No.

The last `Path` wins, i.e. the XAML processor will set the `Path` property to "P2" before the binding is resolved.